# How can I prevent SASS from caching my pages?

Tags: caching, sass

How can I prevent sass from caching my pages so much? Regular caching in the browser is fine of course, but when I'm developing using SASS I sometimes have to refresh the page up to 5 or 6 times before I see my changes. On average I have to refresh 3 times. It slows down development time drastically for me.

Comment: Sass doesn't cache anything.  Are you waiting until the compilation has completed before refreshing?

Comment: The compilation is instant isn't it? Like a second or two? I've been using SASS for about a month now and this is an issue I've only encountered since then. If its not SASS, do you know what might cause me to have to refresh a page 6 times before seeing any changes?

Comment: It depends on your project.  I have one project that takes a good 3-4 seconds to finish compiling.  Smaller projects are faster.  Why don't you take a look at your console (or whatever you're using to compile)?

Comment: I don't think that SASS caches something. It just compiles your files to CSS. So, either your compilation takes too long time or your browser caches the compiled CSS. I'll suggest to check the console's output before to jump directly into the browser and see how much time it takes the compilation.

Comment: I am relatively new to SASS so I didn't realise it was just a very lengthy compilation time. At this stage the project I'm referring to is quite large so one small change must mean compiling the whole file again unfortunately. I am working from the terminal so I don't get much indication of anything other than a change being detected on save. Perhaps I should review my use of SASS and how efficiently I write it, maybe that will reduce compilation time for me. Thank you.